# Implementation of DeferredFirstOrDefault to execute SQL queries in batch with multiple result sets

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-core, deferred-execution

I'm working on my own `DeferredFirstOrDefault()` implementation. I want it to get an `IQueryable` and append `FirstOrDefault()` method to its expression tree.
Using the new `Expression` i want to create a new `IQueryable` which will have a call to `FirstOrDefault()` in its expression tree.
Then i want to use that new `IQueryable` to get the **String SQL Query** containing **SELECT top(1) ...** in it.

I have tried the following code:

```
IQueryable<T> query = queryable;
if (predicate != null)
   query = queryable.Where(predicate);

var method_call_expression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "FirstOrDefault", new Type[] { typeof(T) }, query.Expression);

IQueryable<T> newQuery = query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(method_call_expression);

var string_query = newQuery.ToQueryString();
```

Everything works fine, but as soon as it comes on `.ToQueryString()`, throws an error:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Expression of type 'HNLeye.Modules.Hierarchy.CompanyInfo' cannot be used for return type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable''
```

If you want reference, `Entity Framework Plus` is aleady doing that. It provides `DeferredFirstOrDefault()` method and then we do `FutureValue()` on the returned `DeferredQuery`. Just wanted same thing to be implemented by myself.
This way query is not materialized instantly, but when a round trip is required, all queries in batch are executed in a single SQL Query, which returns `multiple result sets`, to be incremented using `ADO.NET`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Actually you should use `source.Provider.Execute<T>(method_call_expression)`. As I know LINQ translation, and I think I know a lot, you are trying to do something non doable if it is not supported by EF Core.

Comment: But using it will cause query to materialize instantly. I want to save the query in a batch. Just like Entity Framework Plus's `FutureValue()` does. May be its not possible in EF Core. But its certainly doable, i guess.
Well i have checked `.Execute()` it works that way. You are right though.

Comment: You should collect List of `method_call_expression` then use it for generating SQL. EF Core translator you can feed with `Take(1)` instead of `FirstOrDefault`. Actually it needs very deep knowledge of EF Core underneath.

Comment: Thank you so much for advice. This seems a good solution.
But if possible, please provide some good resources to get a more in depth knowledge of EF Core.

Comment: Good source is to look at EF Core source. I don't think that someone created book for that.

Comment: It worked!!!
Thank you soo much. As you said i used `Take()`.

Comment: Note the problem with your code is that `FirstOrDefault` returns a single object, `T` and not a collection of objects `IEnumerable<T>` and also forces an enumeration, it isn't [deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/classification-of-standard-query-operators-by-manner-of-execution). You can't have a query that includes `FirstOrDefault`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by '@Svyatoslav Danyliv', using `Take()` is the way to go instead of `FirstOrDefault()`